# 『ゲーム』条件を満たした時にボタンを削除する方法

Tags: swift, xcode

swift初心者です。現在簡単なゲームアプリ開発に挑戦しており、画面上にボタンを五つ（仮）設置し、当たり外れの概念を設け、外れをタップするとハズレ専用の画像と音声が出力されてゲームオーバーという黒ひげ危機一髪のような仕様のゲームです。

『実装したい機能１：当たりのボタンをタップした時にそのボタンを消したい』
これにより外れのボタンが残っていくことが視覚的に分かりやすくなり、プレイヤーを焦らせることができると思います。

『実装したい機能２：外れのボタンをタップした直後に起動時からなるBGMを停止したい』
if文に.stop()を使用しても上手くいきませんどうかご教授願います。

```
import UIKit

import AVFoundation
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var player:AVAudioPlayer!
var doll:AVAudioPlayer!　//dollはボタンです

//ハズレ音用のAVAudioPlayer
var hazurePlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

//ハズレ時に表示する画像

@IBOutlet weak var hazureImage: UIImageView!

//起動時からなるBGM
func play(soundName:String){
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(soundName)

    try! player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:url)
    player.numberOfLoops = -1
    player.play()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    play("BGM2.mp3")

//最初のハズレ設定
    setupHazure()
    //サウンドの設定はviewDidLoad()の中でやっておくと再生開始までの遅延が少なくなります


   //当たりをタップした時になるサウンド
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("waraiufufu", withExtension: ".wav")!
    try! doll = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    doll.prepareToPlay()


//ハズレをタップした時になるサウンド
let hazureURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("gyaa", withExtension: ".wav")!
    try! hazurePlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: hazureURL)
    hazurePlayer.prepareToPlay()
}

private var hazureTag = 0
func setupHazure() {
    //arc4random_uniform(5)の結果は0...4なので+1して1...5にする
    hazureTag = Int(arc4random_uniform(5)) + 1
}

@IBAction func dolltapped(sender:UIButton){
    print("日本人形\(sender.tag)")
    if sender.tag != hazureTag {
        doll.play()


    } else {
        hazurePlayer.play()
        hazureImage.hidden = false

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*『実装したい機能１：当たりのボタンをタップした時にそのボタンを消したい』*
実際に表示中のViewの階層から削除してしまうという手もあるのですが、単に見た目上消してしまえばいいのであれば、(`hazureImage`等と同様に)`hidden`プロパティを操作して、非表示にしてしまってはいかがでしょうか。(一度設定したview階層からUIButtonなどのコントロール部品を含む子viewを削除してしまうと、予期せぬ副作用のせいでアプリが落ちることもあります。そこら辺を十分理解して自分で対処できるようになるまでは「実際に削除」はしない方が良いでしょう。)

*『実装したい機能２：外れのボタンをタップした直後に起動時からなるBGMを停止したい』*
普通は`stop()`メソッドを呼べば(実際に止まるまで少しだけラグがあります)、演奏中の音は停止するのですが…。ただ、`stop()`で止めてしまうと、次に`play()`を呼んだ時に`prepareToPlay()`相当の処理が再度走るので、少し演奏開始までのラグが大きくなります。`stop()`ではうまくいかなかったというのと合わせて`pause()`を試してみても良いかもしれません。

と言うわけで、上の2点をあなたのコードに入れ込むと、`dolltapped(_:)`メソッドがこんな感じになります。

```
    @IBAction func dolltapped(sender:UIButton){
        if sender.tag != hazureTag {
            doll.play()
            sender.hidden = true //正解のボタンは隠す
        } else {
            hazurePlayer.play()
            hazureImage.hidden = false
            player.pause() //外れならBGMを止める
        }
    }
```

(同じViewControllerを使い回して次の問題を表示するなら、「すべてのボタンの`hidden`プロパティを`false`に設定する」なんて処理などを、次の問題の表示前に入れる必要がありますが。)

`stop()`がうまく動かないのなら`pause()`でもダメな気もするのですが、試してみてうまくいかない場合はコメント等でご連絡ください。

Comment: Le Pere d'OOさん。以前の質問では大変お世話になりました。今回も是非よろしくお願いします。
ご指摘の通りボタンひとつひとつにhiddenにチェックを入れif文を追加しましたがボタンが最初から消えている状態になってしまいます。

音の停止に関してはやはりうまくいきませんでした。

追加情報なのですがこのゲームのスタート画面も作成していてそこでもゲーム画面で使用している起動時から成るBGMをコーディングして使用しているのですが関係あるのでしょうか？ちなみに今のところ画面推移としてはスタート画面⇨ゲーム画面のみストーリーボード上で設定しています。

Comment: _ボタンひとつひとつにhiddenにチェックを入れ_ ⇒初期値としてはhiddenにチェックを入れない(プログラムで書くなら`false`にする)のが「見せる」です。`hidden`は「隠れている」という意味ですからチェックを入れる(`true`にする)のが「消す」になります。効果音に関しては、スタート画面内のインスタンス変数としてAVAudioPlayerを保持している場合、スタート画面のインスタンスが生きている限りそのAVAudioPlayerで再生される音は鳴り続けます。(画面遷移しても遷移元のインスタンスは通常解放されません。)とりあえず、そちらのBGMを再生しないようにして試してみてください。

Comment: Le Pere d'OOさん。無事解決しました。今回の場合hidden状態を条件を満たせば実行するという意味なのでhiddenにチェックを入れておく必要がないということですね。音の方もご指摘の通りにすれば上手くいきました。本当にありがとうございます。

追加で質問なのですがボタンをタップした際に
print("日本人形\(sender.tag)")　の部分が
ブレイクポイントになってしまいました。個人的に解決方を調べ解決できたのですがこのブレイクポイントの必要性となぜここがそれになったのかが理解できませんでした。よければご教授していただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 解決につなげられることができて良かったです。ブレークポイントについてですが、私も時々自分が設定した覚えのない箇所に設定されてしまうということがあるものの、私自身は理由や再現条件とかはわかっていません。(実害はないのですぐに削除して終わりにしています。)OS X/iOS Simulatorのバグが絡んでいる可能性もありそうです。再現性があるのなら、別件として質問スレを立てられたら、詳しい方から何か情報が得られるかもしれません。